# How to swap out hibernate.cfg.xml properties?

Tags: hibernate, orm, properties, configuration-files

I've got a *Hibernate* configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml` where are hard-coded property names like:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mysecretpassword</property>
    ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I want to swap out things like the username and the password to a `.properties`-file. So that I will get the following:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">${jdbc.username}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">${jdbc.password}</property>
    ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

How can I do that? For the **dataSource in Spring** I can use this one in my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
```

*What is the equivalent for Hibernate?*

Answer (score 4):

Remove config parameters from hibernate.cfg.xml and declare the following:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: where should I put jdbc.properties ?

Comment: jdbc.properties - name of file \n jdbc.username is row inside the jdbc.properties like jdbc.username=john. Thus it is different jdbc

Answer (score 3):

If this is an option, you could remove the username and password from the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and declare them in an `hibernate.properties` file that you put on the classpath. But you really need to remove them from the XML configuration file as it overrides properties from the "legacy" properties file. From the documentation:

> #### [3.7. XML configuration file](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig)
>
> An alternative approach to
>   configuration is to specify a full
>   configuration in a file named
>   `hibernate.cfg.xml`. This file can be
>   used as a replacement for the
>   `hibernate.properties` file or, if both
>   are present, to override properties.

If this is not an option (and if you can't configure Hibernate in your Spring configuration file), then you'll have to handle that at build time, using some filtering features from your build tool (Ant, Maven, etc).

Comment: Ok. I put the "hibernate.properties" file in my "/src/java" directory and now it works. Thank you :) But I want to have my jdbc.properties and my hibernate.properties together in one file (because they both have the same setting for username and password). Is there a possibility to do that? Because with the "location" property of my "PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" I cannot access "/src/java". I'm limited to my "/web" folder which is on a different level.

Comment: @Benny Some questions: 1. why does hibernate not use the datasource? 2. why don't you configure hibernate using Spring?

Comment: Hi Pascal. This is a very good question. I do such things because I'm very new to Hibernate and Spring. Therefore I must try out some things first. Having two seperate configuration files was the fastest solution which I have found. If I want to use the datasource for Hibernate then I have to reference it am I right? In some hibernate configs I have seen settings like <property name="connection.datasource">NameOfDataSourceBean</property>. I will check, whether this works...

Answer (score 0):

a Configuration object has a readProperties method (I don't know about what you described though).  If you do plan on using custom properties or overriding hibernate.cfg.xlm, make sure to call configure() first, then setProperty or setProperties after it.